# Set Bamboo variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, variables, bamboo

I'm trying to set a bamboo global variable in a script contained in a batch file. Here is the batch file:

```
@echo off
echo Initial Date: %bamboo_releaseDate%

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set dow=%%i
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
)
set mydate=%month%_%day%_%year%
echo %mydate%

set bamboo_releaseDate = %mydate%
echo Set up date: %bamboo_releaseDate%
```

And here is my output:

```
Initial Date: 140617
06_19_2014
Set up date: 140617
```

As you can see, the variable %bamboo_releaseDate% didn't change at all.
Any idea if it's possible, and how can I do it?

My end goal is to use this variable in the naming of the folders containing my nightly builds (using the standard 'Artifact download' provided by Bamboo).

I have fixed the batch issue, but the updated value isn't available after the script. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set bamboo_releaseDate = %mydate%
                      ^ ^
```

The spaces are included in the name of the variable and in the value. So, you are assigning value to a new variable (that includes a space in its name), not to the existing one (without the space). Replace with

```
set "bamboo_releaseDate=%mydate%"
```

Now, there are no spaces not in the name of the variable nor in its value, and the quoting ensures there is no aditional ending space in the variable content.

Comment: thanks ! But unfortunately, the variable isn't changed after the script. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Scripting tasks run in their own shell, so you can't use this method. Use the Inject Variable Plugin or some other file-based persistence mechanism?

Comment: @JeeBee, sorry, i know something abouth batch files, but i don't know anything about bamboo, I can't answer this part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is the problem with the date parsing.

in your for loop, try to print out %%i:

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
 ECHO i=%%i
 ...
)
```

What do you get?

Working with %DATE% in batch files is dangerous as the format depends on the current system/user settings